# NSdictionary last key return (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have next code for fetching SQLite:

```
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSInteger groupID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
        NSInteger universityID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
        NSInteger averageMark = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        Group *group = [self objectFromArray:self.groups withID:groupID];
        University *university = [self objectFromArray:self.universities withID:universityID];
        NSMutableDictionary *mGroups = university.groups.mutableCopy;
        mGroups[group] = @(averageMark);
        university.groups = [NSDictionary new];
        university.groups = mGroups;
        NSLog(@"%@", university.groups[group]);
    }
}
```

I have problem with last key. So in my all `university` in `university.groups` last key return `(null)` value, but it is there. I use NSLog to see in console, and I see always `(null) (null) (null)` ... it strange, but in next time value appear and problem with value in new key. For example in first time I add `averageMark = 72` for `first key`, in console it return (null), in the second lap I add `averageMark` for `second key`. And now it is all good for `first key`, it return 72, but for `second key` now returning (null). What is problem? Where I wrong with dictionaries?

**EDIT**
I try to check if key exist in NSMutableDictionary. There is no.

```
        mGroups[group] = @(averageMark);
        university.groups = mGroups;
        if (mGroups[group])
            NSLog(@"1234");
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", university.groups[group], mGroups[group], @(averageMark));
```

In console I always see next:

[image]

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Comment: Probably should show `objectFromArray:withID:` since it's not a standard part of Objective-C.  (Might also be a likely location for the problem).